# html variable to php variable in same page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to get the value of textbox to php variable in the same page.
Is there any way to do this?

```
<input type="text" name="Stdgrade" id="Stdgrade" value="6" />
```

Comment: you have to ask a question to get help. there is no other way

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? Whats the context? This is not a good question.

Comment: To send a value from a web browser (html/javascript) to a web server (php etc) you have to do a HTTP request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var foo = function(){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.style.width='1px';img.style.height='1px';img.style.position='absolute';img.style.top='-1px';img.style.left='-1px';
  img.src='putYourPHPfileHere.php?myValue='+document.getElementById('Stdgrade').value;
  img.onload = function(){document.body.removeChild(this);};
  document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```

works for me ;)

in the putYourPHPfileHere.php
you can retrieve the value by

```
$_GET['myValue']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap in in a form element and post it to the page on your webserver. In that page you can retrieve the valie from the $_POST array, like $_POST['Stdgrade']. All of this is pretty basic stuff, so I think you might want to do some tutorials on this first.

Example form:

```
<form id="frmPost" method="post" action="mypage.php">
   <input type="text" name="Stdgrade" id="Stdgrade" value="6" /> 
   <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

If you want to do this through an AJAX api (looking at the tags you added), you might want to take a look at [the jQuery AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). But your question is way to vague to help you more on this.

Answer (score 1):

This will postback your value to a php variable, which will then be shown on screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="Stdgrade" id="Stdgrade" value="6" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
        <?php
            $var = $_GET['Stdgrade'];
            echo $var;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to post the value to the same page. Then you have to get the value from the request like:

```
$value = $_REQUEST["Stdgrade"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the input must be within the form that causes request

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is run server side this is not possible. You would have to submit the form and retrieve the variable on the next page load.