# How to execute external php from Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm working on a javascript application, and i've organized things as follow:

- a table is displayed on screen (table is coming from a MySQL database)
- user take a decision, may be to delete a row of the table, clicking on an icon (NOT A FORM)
- want to launch an external php file with a sintax like `<<tabledelete.php?codetokill='XXXXXX'>>`
- refresh the original page

Unfortunately i can't find the right way to call the external php, something works but i'm not able to get back to the main page, and so on

can someone please give me some suggestion? Am I using a wrong approach? TY to all.

EDIT
Just for testing pourpose i've implemented following code as suggested:

```
JAVASCRIPT (this is a funcion called bay a button with onclick option)
function fn_deleterow(numrig,cod,descr) {
    messaggio="Hai deciso di eliminare ("+numrig+") "+cod+" - "+descr;
    var scelta = confirm(messaggio);
    if (scelta) {
        document.write('Ok delete')
        $.ajax({
        url: "PHPTest.php",
        type: "POST"
        })
        document.write('Happy ending')
        document.location.reload(true)
    }
}

PHP FILE
<?php
echo 'HERE WE ARE WITH PHP<abr>';
?>
```

I can see the "ok delete" and the "happy ending" messages, and the page reloads, but no "here we are with php" at all... where am i wrong?

Comment: simple use ajax to call a php page from javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full Javascript library for this simple thing might be a total overkill. Have a look at this over here:

**[html variable to php variable in same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899791/html-variable-to-php-variable-in-same-page/7899999#7899999)**

This answer pretty much is what you are looking for I guess :)

```
<script>
var foo = function(variable_to_be_passed_to_php){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.style.width='1px';img.style.height='1px';img.style.position='absolute';img.style.top='-1px';img.style.left='-1px';
  img.src='putYourPHPfileHere.php?myValue='+variable_to_be_passed_to_php;
  img.onload = function(){document.body.removeChild(this);};
  document.body.appendChild(img);
};
</script>
```

and in your table do something like:

```
<td onclick="foo(1234)">
```

or

in the **putYourPHPfileHere.php**
you can retrieve the value by

```
$_GET['myValue']
```

Comment: well, yes and no;1st of all thank you, to be honest is REALLY what i need, to pass a variable to local php, but i don't want to use a form... so i was thinking to build an external php functions library to call with parameters... totally stuck here...

Comment: @RobertoAlfieri That is why I suggested this answer. But I guess I need to know your HTML markup, so I can send you a working example :)

Comment: i've placed some code above, so it could be helpful... TY very much!

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript` is client side language where `PHP` is server side. You can call `PHP` variables already in the page in `Javascript`. But you cant execute some `PHP` code using Javascript. Because `PHP` is executed in server only. Javascript cant communicate with Server. It can only work with browser.

You can use `AJAX` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For example: With Jquery / ajax request:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.myclass", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var send_uri = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: send_uri,
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function(responde){
           $("table.mytable").html(responde);
        }
    });     
});
```

and at your test.php page you can catch GET params from the url and depending on them to make your queries and return the RESPONDE. 
In my case the responde is in HTML format, you can set it as you want it .. read about that here - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Comment: Just for testing pourpose i've implemented following lines: